# how to encode inputstream to quoted-printable inputstream

Tags: java, encoding, inputstream, quoted-printable

Like org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream which converts given inputstream to base64inputstream, i want class which should converts inputstream to quoted-printable inputstream.

Please help to find one.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I used james code.

org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.Base64InputStream;
org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.QuotedPrintableInputStream;

I used these two for respective encoding.